# In Jquery how to remove dot "." from a string except decimal dot i.e., dot in between numbers?

Tags: jquery

i want to allow price amount which dot not contains characters as well as dots"."  but it should allow decimal dot in between numbers.

symbol = symbol.replace(/./g, "");
myString = myString.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');

Comment: what exactly do you want? a function that will tell you if a string you have is a valid price or not?

Comment: @Jagdish have you got your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is,

```
my_string.replace(/([^\w.\s]|(?!\d)\.(?!\d))+/g, '')
```

e.g.

```
$ a = "asasdasdas....... 3.4 asdasd ......"
$ a.replace(/([^\w.\s]|(?!\d)\.(?!\d))+/g, '');
$ "asasdasdas 3.4 asdasd "
```

Removed all dots from a string, except decimal point.